# Blender video editor how to undo fade out

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I added fade out to a video strip in blender.
How can I remove this fade out.
No properties are showing for fade duration ect.

Answer (score 2):

if you added the fadein/out like this:

[image]

[image]

select first strip and right click on opacity -> clear keyframes

same for second strip.

[image]

result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you select the strip and right click you'll have an option to Clear Fade.

[image]

If Adjust Last Operation is checked:

[image]

You can change the fade settings after applying it here:

[image]

Alternatively, you can change ex. the File Browser area to Graph Editor and edit the keyframes of the fade manually:

[image]